# Rounding numbers to ten

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do seems rather simple, but I can't get it to work with the php.net documentation..

Numbers should always be rounded to "tens"

So:

1 -> 10

7 -> 10

12 -> 20

18 -> 20

23 -> 30

35 -> 40

Comment: cannot you use mod and then add 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$rounded_num = round($orig_num / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read documentation about [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

```
round($number, -1);
```

Comment: **"but I can't get it to work with the php.net documentation"**

Plus, haven't been able to access the damn php.net because of a malware notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use round() function.
But if you want manual way, you can use something like that:

```
$number = 189;
$length = strlen((string)$number);
$div = '1';
for ($i=0;$i<$length-1;$i++){
$div .= '0';
}
$result = (int)$div*(ceil($number/$div));
```

**$result = 200**

Comment: Well, 189 should round to 190 :)

Comment: I thought purpose was slightly different. ))